# Algorithm puzzle - tricky server to client file transfer

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

Scenario:

- A client has to get a file from a server. He can just send a request to server and start file download. This is not what we want. Client has a limitation that it can't receive a lot of data (say, file size of x bytes and client can receive at max y bytes and x >>>> y). There is no such restriction on sending data. That means client can send as much data to server as he wants. No restrictions on server also. Assume that the file is already compressed and file size cannot be reduced.

I will tell one really bad solution:

- client will ask the size of file from server and then send all possible combinations of the file to the server. For wrong combination the server will not respond and for the correct one it will send a success response (if the server responds with a failure response in case of wrong combinations then we won't gain anything because the total size of responses will become >= the filesize itself). This will take months to transfer a few mB file but filesize to server-to-client-data-transfer ratio will be best.

What is the most efficient way? We are trying to maximize the above ratio while keeping the transfer time reasonable.

Comment: I don't get this question at all. Wouldn't the client just tell the server how much to receive from position 0, where "how much to receive" is the number which corresponds to how much it can receive as per your limitation? Then go to the next position after that, ie. if it can only receive 1K at a time, first request 1024 bytes from position 0, then 1024 bytes from position 1024, then 1024 from 2048, etc. What is the problem here?

Comment: And what do you mean by "send all possible combinations of the file to the server"? If you have 1 file there is only 1 combination so surely that sentence means something other than what you wrote. Can you please show some examples?

Comment: So what are you saying is that the client is generating random files uploads it to the server and the server responds if it matches the needed file? Do you now anything about the file structure or file size? Why not download the file in parts? Is this a theoretical question? Why is the receiving part limited but the sending part not?

Comment: @Lasse - The restriction is not on per request but total transfer. If a file is 3 bit long then all possible combinations means - 000, 001, 010, ..., 111 (total 8). I hope its clear now.

Comment: No, that did not make it clearer. So you're saying the client cannot receive the whole file no matter what because it will run out of allotted bandwidth before the whole file can be received, regardless of the order in which it attempts to receive it?

Comment: @Hector - Not random, but a specific sequence. For example first 000, then 001 etc, as above. Client can ask server about the file size and structure. Can't download in parts as the total transfer is restricted. Yes theoretical question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - yes client cannot download the whole file in traditional way as filesize > total allowed download data.

Comment: OK, is this a *practical* problem, I mean, do you actually have this problem in your software?

Comment: Its a theoretical puzzle.

Comment: Then I would suggest your reword the puzzle and ask on CS theory or the new Puzzle site or something. You could reword it as follows: I have written down a large essay. Your job is to deduce this essay. You can not ask me to read it or give it to you. You can ask me any other question you could think of, but I have a finite number times I can answer your question before you need to have the solution ready. For instance, the text could be 1000 characters long, and I can only answer 10 questions from you. You can, however, give me as long and as many questions you want. How would you do this?

Comment: This sounds somehow similar to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: My naive solution would be to ask for the length of the file, and then  pick a sweet spot size. Then I would start uploading all combinations of files that length (sweet spot size), and ask the server to return the index of the next matching block of the file. This index has a size as well so you need to pick the sweet spot size so that you can get all the blocks in the allotted download quota. You could combine this with the MD5 approach in perreal's answer to do a lot of the verification on the client.

Comment: Maybe you can calculate/compare the CRC for parts of the file or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client sends the filename, server sends back a hash (md5) of the contents of the file. Client tries all possible combinations to get the exact same md5. Then sends back the guess, server verifies.

Comment: If you calculated how many pieces you could split the file into and still end up below the allotted bandwidth quota you would drastically reduce the number of files to calculate as well, you would basically do your suggestion on a block-by-block of the entire file.

Comment: if storage space is not a problem on the client and you know somethings about the file content you could even keep a rainbow table so you don´t need to compute anything, just a lookup (for small file sizes of course)

Comment: "Client tries all possible combinations to get the exact same md5" - this is just ridiculous. not only isn't it practically feasible (all combinations? really?), but incorrect: many files can have the same md5.

Comment: Together with HectorLector's suggestion of asking the count of 0s and 1s the guess work can be made better.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most efficient way?

Unless you can compress the data down to *y* bytes, it's **not possible** at all.

All attempts to solve the problem by guessing are futile, as the ACK/NACK answers for the guesses are also part of the communication. To distinguish between two data of x bytes, you need x bytes of answers.

Take a look at it from a different angle: in your guess game the whole task of sending the guesses can be replaced by an automated machine, sending one guess after the other. Heck, the server could do the enumeration itself. Then it would simply say: hey, the #1051351 attempt was the correct one. But to transfer that, again, you need *x* bytes. As you can see, communication in the other direction is totally irrelevant.

Comment: What if the there is no NACK, just no reply, so there is no communication happening when the guess is false, so the number of received bytes is not affected by wrong guesses.

Comment: ACKing can be made to occur only for correct guess. All other guesses will see no response from server. If the retry also lead to no response then it will be assumed wrong. Not a bulletproof strategy but quite acceptable

Comment: @HectorLector: you cannot have a "half bit", how will the receiver know which message the ACK belongs to?

Comment: Example: Right value = 0, client guess = 1. Send 1 to server, after x time-units no reply, client knows that 1 was wrong therefor 0 is the right value. Number of received bytes = 0. (assuming the server is always on and working and there is no other connection failure).

Comment: @HectorLector: in real life communication is done on unreliable channels, so the absence of a message cannot be used to transfer information.

Comment: In real life I don´t have a restriction of total number of received bytes ;-)

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. It seems this is not possible practically. But since this is a theoretical puzzle, we can assume that no response means wrong guess

Answer (score -1):

Okay if I understand you correctly there is a limitation of total bytes received by the client and he needs to get a file from a server (or at least figure out the content of that file).

Options:

- Download file normally will need FILESIZE bytes - not possible if FILESIZE > MAX_RECEIVE_BYTES
- Client starts at position 0, guesses the byte, send (guess + position) to server. Server responds by either YES = correct, NOTHING = wrong. With this approach you will need to also receive at least FILESIZE bytes. And you need at max FILESIZE * FILESIZE tries.
- Guess more bytes (N) at once. This will give you a number of received bytes = FILESIZE/N.

So i think the best/fastest way is just to download the file normally (in parts if thats the limitation).
Otherwise you want to find a value for N where FILESIZE/N < MAX_RECEIVE_BYTES.

**Edit**:
The only other thing i can think of, is that the client asks the server about the number of 0 and 1 in the file, so he can make more educated guesses, and therefore reducing the space of possible combinations = number of requests = faster.

Comment: This is the same solution as the one described with the problem where N = filesize. Yes client has to figure out the file content